# change color of loading tile

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, rendering

I have my osm server with mapnik, it works fine but now I want to change the background color( black to white), how can I do that? Is it a server or client configuration?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the old Mapnik XML styles, the background colour is defined at the beginning of the XML file:

```
<Map background-color="#b5d0d0" srs="&srs900913;" minimum-version="2.0.0">
```

You may as well look into the `layer-shapefiles.xml.inc` file and look for the `coast-poly` style:

```
<PolygonSymbolizer fill="#ffffff"/>
```